# Angular 2 utility method to review differences between two objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a utility method built-in for Angular 2 that can create a comparison between two objects of same type and show differences? I would need a deep comparison.

`@Input` + `ngOnChange` seems to return something similar, however I need it in a service on demand.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to perform a `JSON.stringify()` for both objects and then compare the resulting strings. It depends however, how exactly you want to compare the objects.

Comment: This is not what I would like to do. I would like to receive a descriptor object that highlights the differences.